# Add textbox via Jquery is not working in chrome

Tags: javascript

In the below code I use to add new text-box, but this code is not working in Google chrome, it seems to be working in Firefox.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btnSubmit" id="add-box" value="Add item" />

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.control-group #add-box').click(function(){
        var n = $('.text-box').length + 1;
        if( 100 < n ) {
            alert('Stop it!');
            return false;
        }
        var box_html = $('<p class="text-box"> <input type="text" name="boxes[]" value="" id="box' + n + '" /><input type="text" name="boxes1[]" value="" id="box1' + n + '" /><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btnSubmit" id="remove-box" value="Remove item" /> </p>');
        box_html.hide();
        $('.control-group p.text-box:last').after(box_html);
        box_html.fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
    });
    $('.control-group').on('click', '#remove-box', function(){
        $(this).parent().css( 'background-color', '#FF6C6C' );
        $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $(this).remove();
            $('.box-number').each(function(index){
                $(this).text( index + 1 );
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your code, I think your problem is with the duplicated remove ids.  Try the following:

```js
$('#add-box').click(function() {
  var n = $('.text-box').length + 1;
  if (100 < n) {
    alert('Stop it!');
    return false;
  }
  var box_html = $('<p class="text-box"><input type="text" name="boxes[]" value="" id="box' + n + '" /><input type="text" name="boxes1[]" value="" id="box1' + n + '" /><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success remove-box" name="btnSubmit" id="remove-box' + n + '" value="Remove item" /> </p>'); // change the remove button so id's are unique and add a class
  
  $('.control-group').append(box_html.hide()); // i have just changed this selector for this example
  
  box_html.fadeIn('slow');
  return false;
});
$('.control-group').on('click', '.remove-box', function() {  // target the class (if you target a duplicated id, it will always only return the first element with that id)
  $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#FF6C6C').fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $(this).remove();
    $('.box-number').each(function(index) {
      $(this).text(index + 1);
    });
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-group">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btnSubmit" id="add-box" value="Add item" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

since at the first click chrome is not able to find $('.control-group p.text-box:last').after(box_html); so it will not append anything and so on.

please change your code as below

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(' #add-box').click(function(){

        var n = $('.text-box').length + 1;

        if( 100 < n ) {            
            alert('Stop it!');
            return false;
        }
        var box_html = $('<p class="text-box"> <input type="text" name="boxes[]" value="" id="box' + n + '" /><input type="text" name="boxes1[]" value="" id="box1' + n + '" /><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btnSubmit" id="remove-box" value="Remove item" /> </p>');
        box_html.hide();
        if($('.control-group p.text-box:last').length>0) // if there is already then append after it.
            $('.control-group p.text-box:last').after(box_html);
        else
            $('body').append(box_html); // else add textboxes to body or your class below button

        box_html.fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
    });
    $('.control-group').on('click', '#remove-box', function(){
        $(this).parent().css( 'background-color', '#FF6C6C' );
        $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $(this).remove();
            $('.box-number').each(function(index){
                $(this).text( index + 1 );
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```